# Child element overlapping parent element width

Tags: html, css

Why is my input element wider than my label that it is inside? Should My input not be the same width as the containing label? As I have said width:100% and it is inside the label?

```
       <label class="km-listview-label question" style="height: 2.5em; display:inline-block; width:20%;">

    <input style="left:0; width:100%; display:inline-block; " data-description="Height" data-control="Text" data-code="Q3" data-type="Measurement" type="text">
    </label>
<label style="display:inline;">m</label>
```

How do I make the input the same width as the label it is inside? Because I need the "m" to show up to the right of the input, so that it is like a meters unit measurement. However, when I type a lot of characters, they cover the "m". Here are images of the padding of the label and the input, using a debugging tool to look at elements:

Label:

[image]

Input:

[image]

Comment: It's eveident your problem is in your CSS (which you didn't add). I tried your HTML alone and it works fine

Comment: @Fabio Is it possible that it behaves differently because I am using jquery.append() to get the html onto the page rather than hardcoding html into an html page?

Comment: it's possible but unlikely, looks more like some additional CSS is affecting it